# Replacing text in an email with a picture from the clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a report that I send out daily.
In it there is a linked image to a range that I need to paste into an email and send.
I have the email saved as an outlook template file that I modify as necessary when I need to.
The code I have runs from Excel.
I create an Outlook object and open the Outlook email from the .oft template file, then I want to find the identifier text (*INSERT IMAGE HERE*) and replace it with the linked image from Excel, which has been copied from the clipboard. 
 I am trying to add it as an InLineShape so that it behaves properly in the body of the email.
I have been attempting to do it with a defined WordEditor from the body of the email.
I looked into HTML to do it, but I decided the WordEditor object would be a better approach. 
 After I paste it, I need to set the scale height to 0.75 so that it is displayed properly.
From there, just click send.

Here is a quick sample of my code:

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(templatePath) 
OutlookEmail.Display 'Just for code checking
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Sheet").Pictures("Summary Email Screenshot").Copy 
Set EmailText = OutlookEmail.GetInspector.WordEditor 
With EmailText.Range.Find 
    .ClearFormatting
    .Execute findText:="*INSERT IMAGE HERE*", MatchWholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=True, _
        MatchWildcards:=False, ReplaceWith:="^c", Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With

EmailText.InlineShapes(EmailText.InlineShapes.count).ScaleHeight = 75 
'OutlookEmail.Send
```

The problem arises with that last line before I send it.
What happens is it is not inserted as an InLineShape, but just a shape so that it floats on top of the text.
I need it as an InLineShape so that the content after the image moves down and is displayed rather than being covered by it. 
 I've been scowering forums for a while to try to find an answer but to no avail.
I am pretty well versed in Excel VBA, but this is my first attempt at Outlook and Word VBA so please, bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when an image is pasted Word will use the setting Insert/paste pictures as from File/Options/Advanced, section "Cut, copy and paste". So on some machines an image might be pasted as an InlineShape and on others as a Shape.

If you were simply pasting in the code then using `PasteSpecial` it would be possible to specify inline or with text wrap using the corresponding WdOLEPlacement enumeration value of either wdFloatOverText or wdInLine.

Since the paste command is coming from the `^c` replacement text this approach won't work for this situation. That means the Options setting will need to be changed. And, in order for this to be user-friendly, at the end of the code it should be changed back.

Here's some sample code demonstrating how to check the current option, change it if necessary, and reset at the end of the procedure. I'm not familiar with using Word through the Outlook object model, but I think I've correctly instantiated an object for the `Word.Application` so that VBA executing in Excel or Outlook will know what `Options` are meant. Except for the last line, this should come between `Set` and `With` in the code sample in the question.

```
Dim wrapType As Long
Dim wordApp as Object

Set wordApp = EMailText.Application
wrapType = wordApp.Options.PictureWrapType
If wrapType <> wdWrapMergeInline Then
    wordApp.Options.PictureWrapType = wdWrapMergeInline
End If
'Do other things, then reset

wordApp.Options.PictureWrapType = wrapType
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. If it helps, I am completely open to using a method besides .Find and .Execute. I was using them just to find the text I needed. If there was a way to set the cursor to where that text is and delete it, then I could use PasteSpecial to insert the image and avoid the option setting and resetting.

Comment: @Bassta you could use the Find, as you have it, without a Replace. But declare a `Range` variable for the Find (`Dim rng as Word.Range : Set rng = EMailText.Content : With rng.Find`) If the Find.Execute is successful (returns a Boolean) then `rng.Delete : rng.PasteSpecial...`. I think either is fine, it would be a question of personal taste.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it pasted the picture as an inline but two things happened that were unintended: the EMailText.Delete line deleted everything in the email before my identifier and the line that it crashed on before that I outlined in my question is still failing even though the image was pasted inline as required.

Comment: @Bassta I don't see anything about any crashing in the relevant part of the question. It shouldn't be deleting "everything" if you used a Range variable properly - but for that I'd need to see the code you use. If you're still interested in that approach best might be to ask about this other approach in a new question, where you can post the code. I'd leave this one and mark it as "the answer" since there may be other people it could help...

Comment: Ok, I found out why the text before my identifier was being deleted with some trial and error. It turns out that I needed to change the .MatchWildcards argument to false and that stopped happening, but I still cannot scale the pasted image.

Comment: @Bassta That definitely requires a new question. However, I did answer pretty much exactly the same thing some time ago... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585820/select-pasted-image-in-word/52589314#52589314

Comment: I figured out what was wrong and I will add my solution here just for anyone who comes across this in the future. I was using the WordEditor.Content.InlineShapes function instead of WordEditor.InlineShapes. When using the latter, the image resized correctly. Thanks Cindy for all your help. +1 for thoroughly explaining your answer

Comment: @Bassta Glad it helped :-) When you have everything sorted to your satisfaction could you take a moment to go through these comments and flag the ones you consider no longer relevant to the Q&A as "No longer needed", please? And let me know (before you do that) if you think anything in the comments belongs in the "Answer". Or you can put that info in at the end of the Answer (use the [edit] link below it and I'll "clean it up" later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184338/discussion-between-bassta-and-cindy-meister).